# How to use xtext language services from Angular

Tags: xtext, eclipse-orion

I'm working on a DSL developed using xtext. I am using autocomplete using orion editor. It works great with the auto generated web editor. But, we want to integrate it with another web app developed using Angular 4. I got to configure the editor, but somehow all calls to language services (e.g. Occurrences, hover, etc) fails with `404`. While same calls work fine with the auto generated embedded editor. What I'm missing here?

Here is how my code to create editor looks like in typescript:

```
xtext.createEditor({
    'serviceUrl': 'http://localhost:8080/xtext-service',
    'syntaxDefinition': 'http://localhost:8080/xtext-resources/generated/dsl-syntax.js',
    'parentClass': 'xtext-editor',
    'enableCors': true,
    'loadFromServer': false
  })
```

If I compare AJAX calls made by angular app and web editor, significant difference I see is, the web editor sends few cookies, which angular app doesn't. Can that be a reason? If so, how can I fix angular app accordingly?

Comment: How did you add xtext in your Angular project ?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is stuck with the same situation, I resolved it by adding

```
sendFullText: true
```

to the config object passed to the `createEditor` method. This property configures the editor to use language services in stateless mode and doesn't expect cookie/session to be passed.